# Android firebase chat app getting user data has delay

Tags: android, firebase

I'm making a Android chatting app with firebase.
When Framgment is creating a view, I try to get user lisst,
But it has delay like 4~5 sec. Is there faster way to get data immediately with firebase?

```
Firebase firebase = new Firebase(AppDefine.FIREBASE_URL).child("friendlist-"+ac.getUserId());
firebase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        HashMap<String,String> map = (HashMap) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        mFriends.add(new ChatUserInfo(map.get("id"),map.get("name")));
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks correct, so won't be the cause of delays. More likely it's an infrastructural thing, where your connection to the Firebase servers is simply taking that long. There's nothing your code can do about that.

Comment: How big is the user list? If it takes 4-5 secs to download, this makes sense.

Comment: I'm just start developping so I only have 5 user list. Maybe connection to firebase getting delay?